# Observe an input which rendered in uiOutput in a module

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I am trying to observe an input which rendered in uiOutput in a module.

I tried the following reprex code:

```
my_modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  uiOutput(ns("ui1")),
  verbatimTextOutput(ns("text1"))
  )
}

my_modServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$ui1 <- renderUI({
        actionButton("btn", "Click me!")
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$btn, handlerExpr = {
        output$text1 <- renderPrint(paste0("Button is clicked"))
      })
    }
  )
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  my_modUI("my_mod")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_modServer("my_mod")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It didn't work. What I am expecting to see is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B0Oq.gif)

Could you help me to solve this problems with using Shiny modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are in a module you need to wrap the button id in `ns()` for which you can use the `session$ns`. See the part on using `renderUI` in a module at https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/:

```
my_modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("ui1")),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("text1"))
  )
}

my_modServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$ui1 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        
        actionButton(ns("btn"), "Click me!")
      })

      observeEvent(input$btn, handlerExpr = {
        output$text1 <- renderPrint(paste0("Button is clicked"))
      })
    }
  )
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  my_modUI("my_mod")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_modServer("my_mod")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]